# Windows 10 - Airplane mode stuck On on desktop PC without wireless devices?

Tags: windows-10, airplane-mode

I have done a fresh install of Windows 10 last year on my desktop computer. It does not have any wireless devices, only a single onboard network interface, and for some reason the Airplane Mode is available and seems to be stuck to the On position. It doesn't seem to affect my network connectivity, but I just find it annoying to see the icon enabled and that I can't turn it off.

It seems like a glitch. If I open the settings panel for it, and try to disable it, the slider just springs back to On.

See below:

[image: screenshot_of_airplane_mode_stuck_on]

You can clearly see I have no wireless devices, and yet the feature is turned on ?

I've found a ton of other posts for the same issue however it was all for people using laptops or computers with wireless devices on them, and for all of them it was affecting their connectivity. It's not my case.

Has anyone else seen this and have an idea what I could check to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a UPS attached to your machine with USB, that can cause Windows 10 to assume you are on a portable device and thus require Flight Mode.

This was the case for me and I was unable to turn Flight Mode off. My machine was upgraded from Windows 7 and since, I have spurious connection issues causing huge lock ups on the machine. I am hoping my resolving the Flight Mode issue resolves the network issues.

Comment: So how does one in specific detail prevent the behavior?

Comment: I do have a UPS attached indeed ! I never thought of that, that good to know, but Windows should be smart enough to detect the UPS. It does on Ubuntu... That said, my problem's solved anyway as I have switched completely to Linux by now. No more Windows for me! Thanks for the hint though!

Comment: Should be smart enough, indeed. There are lots of user interface design issues with WIndows 10 I have found. Unfortunately for me the flight mode being stuck didn't resolve any of my networking issues.